# ArcMap Crashes because of increasing memory usage

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, memory, serious-application-error

I have this code and I tried to delete all the layers it creates to enhance it's performance. However, ArcMap crashes after about 200+ files. I get a message that says ArcGIS had a Serious error and it asks me if I want to report it

I am new to the subject, but I checked the internet for solutions and none of them worked (e.g. cleared cache).

The `lyr[number]` depends on the rank of the layer in the TOC.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:\\Directory"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fcs = arcpy.ListRasters()
for fc in fcs:
    # Local variables:
    ascii_input= str("E:\\Directory\\"+fc)
    colors = "colors"
    ascii_out = "ascii_out"
    
    # Process: Build Pyramids And Statistics
    x1=arcpy.BuildPyramidsandStatistics_management(ascii_input, "INCLUDE_SUBDIRECTORIES", "BUILD_PYRAMIDS", "CALCULATE_STATISTICS", "NONE")
    
    # Process: Define Projection
    x2=arcpy.DefineProjection_management(ascii_input, "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")
    arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()
    # Process: Make Raster Layer
    arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(ascii_input, ascii_out, "", "-97.154167 40.133331 -90.207778 44.53785", "")
    del(x1)
    del(x2)
    # Process: Apply Symbology From Layer
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(ascii_out, colors)
    ############### ##################################################################

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        x=str(fc)
        if elm.text == "344":
            elm.text = x[2:4]+"/"+x[4:6]+"/20"+x[0:2]+" "+x[6:8]+":"+x[8:10] #change text to the date time
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr[8]) #make sure it's the correct layer
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"E:\\IFC4GISJPEG\\"+str(fc)+".jpg")
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        if elm.text == x[2:4]+"/"+x[4:6]+"/20"+x[0:2]+" "+x[6:8]+":"+x[8:10]:           #change text from date time back to 344 (a random value I chose)
            elm.text = "344"    
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr[7]) #make sure it's the correct
    arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not absolutely certain where the memory consumption is coming from. It could be ArcMap itself from loading several hundred layers, even if they are removed from the map document. It could be from python.
I tried as best as I could here to reduce the python memory footprint, but I think this could just be a problem with loading so many layers into ArcMap, even if you remove them again.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:\\Directory"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fcs = arcpy.ListRasters()
# Moving several variables out of the loop
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
colors = "colors"
ascii_out = "ascii_out"

#Creating an array of only the text elements you are working with, so array is not redefined repeated in loop
elms = [item for item in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT") if item == "344"]

for fc in fcs:
    # Process: Build Pyramids And Statistics
    x1=arcpy.BuildPyramidsandStatistics_management(arcpy.env.workspace + "\\" + fc, "INCLUDE_SUBDIRECTORIES", "BUILD_PYRAMIDS", "CALCULATE_STATISTICS", "NONE")

    # Process: Define Projection
    x2=arcpy.DefineProjection_management(arcpy.env.workspace + "\\" + fc, "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")
    arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()
    # Process: Make Raster Layer
    arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(ascii_input, ascii_out, "", "-97.154167 40.133331 -90.207778 44.53785", "")
    del(x1)
    del(x2)
    # Process: Apply Symbology From Layer
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(ascii_out, colors)
    x = str(fc)
    x = x[2:4]+"/"+x[4:6]+"/20"+x[0:2]+" "+x[6:8]+":"+x[8:10]
    for elm in elms:
        elm.text = x        #change text to the date time
    del(x)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[8])                #make sure it's the correct layer
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"E:\\IFC4GISJPEG\\"+str(fc)+".jpg")
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[7])                #make sure it's the correct layer
    arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()
for elm in elms:
    elm.text = "344"
```